# Aggregation: Project dotted field doesn't seem to work

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a database containing this document:

```
{"_id":{"$id":"xxx"},"duration":{"sec":137,"usec":0},"name":"test"}
```

If I call db.collection.aggregate with this pipeline:

```
{$project:{_id: 0, name: 1, duration: 1, seconds: "$duration.sec"}}
```

I get this result:

```
{"result":[{"duration":{"sec":137,"usec":0},"name":"test"}],"ok":1}
```

Why does the result not have a 'seconds' field? Have I used the wrong projection syntax?

I'm not entirely sure of the version of mongodb the server is running. I'm using the 1.3.1 php driver with php 5.4.3, but the server may be older than that - perhaps by about half a year?

Answer (score 3):

According to the MongoDB documentation on [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/):

> You may also use $project to rename fields. Consider the following
>   example:

```
db.article.aggregate(
 { $project : {
     title : 1 ,
     page_views : "$pageViews" ,
     bar : "$other.foo"
 }} );
```

> This operation renames the pageViews field to page_views, and renames the foo field in the other sub-document as the top-level
>    field bar.

That example seems to match-up pretty good with what you are trying to do.

I know 10gen officially released the aggregation framework with MongoDB v2.2.  Check out the [current production release](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads), which I believe is 2.2.3.  If you are running on a prior development version, there could be something odd going on with aggregation.

Comment: Ah, if it was all released in one go then I should have it; renaming the field (without using a "." anywhere) works just fine. It's only when accessing a sub-field that it doesn't work. I'll try to find out the version anyway since it's something I probably should know!

Answer (score 0):

As Bryce said, I'm currently using MongoDB 2.6 through the shell and the $project pipeline is working for renaming nested fields as you do.

```
db.article.aggregate({$project:{'_id': 0, 'name': 1, 'duration': 1, 'seconds': '$duration.sec'}}
```

I've not tried yet trough the python or php drivers but my former pipelines with the last pymongo worked very well.